# Adding JSON data to DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Hoping someone can access this for me cause I cannot figure it out.

The data is successfully being received, however the data won't load into the table.  There's no error message.  It just simply won't do it.  This worked previously when I used an ajax call within the DataTable, but when I move the Ajax call outside of the DataTable creation then it does not work.

Example JSON data:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Fred"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Tommy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Function call to get JSON:

```
function getJSON() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/GetList",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        drawDataTable('Table', data);
    });
}
```

Drawing the DataTable

```
function drawDataTable(divId, data) {
    var table = $('#' + divId).DataTable({
        data: data,
        dataSrc: "",
        columnDefs: [
            { "targets": [0], "data": "Id" },
            { "targets": [1], "data": "Name" }
        ]
    });
    return table;
}
```

I then send this large array of data (1000 array elements) to my Datatable function via `function drawDataTable(divId, data)`

And within that DataTable function I use:

```
data: data,
dataSrc: ""
```

I have also tried removing the `dataSrc` and also making it `dataSrc: "data"` but neither worked.

Comment: What DataTable are you using? Can you share a working example to show this problem?

Comment: There's to little code here to point definitively to a problem, although my guess is that you're requesting the info from your database, then the table gets drawn (before the data gets back from the data base, so nothing to show in the table), then the data arrives back. Make sure you are not drawing the table until the data is available to be used.

Comment: @TJBlackman that's what I'm thinking too.  That the table is being drawn before the data is done being retrieved.  However, take a look at my function I added to the post.  I only call this drawDataTable upon the Ajax call being done?

Comment: @TJBlackman I also verified that I have the data before creating the datatable being doing a `console.log` on the data parameter in the `drawDataTable` function.  Thus the data is there for the table to use.

Comment: You said you've tried `dataSrc: "data"`, but that's the string "data". Try instead using the actual `data` variable: `dataSrc: data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the structure of JSON, please try **data.data**

```
 function drawDataTable(divId, data) {
        var table = $('#' + divId).DataTable({
            data: data.data, //updated here
            dataSrc: "",
            columnDefs: [
                { "targets": [0], "data": "Id" },
                { "targets": [1], "data": "Name" }
            ]
        });
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply!  How did you figure this out?  The DataTables website has examples with my exact same JSON example but they didn't even use `data: data.data`

Comment: I was also able to remove `dataSrc: ""` and have it still work.  I suppose that's not necessary unless your JSON data has a different parent node other than `data`

Comment: Yes, `data` is the default prop DT is looking for, if nothing else specified.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are writing your code inside this function

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// your code
}
```

because anything written outside this, might not work properly, specially when you are working with **dataTables.**

Also, you can write this code in the following way ( if this helps )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function drawDataTable(divId,data) {
   var t = $('#'+ divId).DataTable();
   var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
   dataObj.forEach(element => {
      t.row.add([
            element.Id,
            element.name
         ]).draw(false)
    });
 }})
```

Comment: I apologize for that typo.  I changed some of the code to have it not replicate what I am working with in reality.  I changed string values that can be interchanged.  Nice catch though.